# filebeat modify data enriching json from other sources

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Log format consist on json encoded in line by line format.
Each line is

```
{data,payload:/local/path/to/file}
{data,payload:/another/file}
{data,payload:/a/different/file}
```

the initial idea is configure logstash to use http input, write a java (or anything) daemon that get the file, parse it line by line, replace the payload with the content of file, and send the data to logstash.

I can't modify how the  server work, so log format can't be changed.
Logstash machine are different host, so no direct access to files.
Logstash can't mount a shared folder from the server_host.
I can't open port apart a single port for logstash due to compliance of the solution that need ot respect some silly rules that aren't under my control.

Now, to save some times and have a more reliable than a custom-made solution, it's possible to configure filebeat to process every line of json, before sending it to logstash, adding to it

```
{data,payload:content_of_the_file}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Filebeat* won't be able to do advanced transformations of this kind, as it is only meant to forward logs, it can't even do basic string processing like *logstash* does. I suggest you write a custom script that does this transformation & writes the output to a different file.

You can use *filebeat* to send the contents of this new file to *logstash*.